# get rid of line that is not starting with specific word

Tags: sed

I want to get rid of a line from a python file which is not starting with `def`.

`thefile.py` has

```
def showBuilder():
   """ Do something
       And build show
   """

showBuilder()
```

Now I want to leave the line def showBuilder as is but want to get rid of the line showbuilder() at the bottom

I tried

```
sed '/^def / s/showBuilder()//' thefile.py
```

but this is returning

```
def :
   """ Do something
       And build show
   """

showBuilder()
```

would love to use anything that works, sed is just my try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So match the line and the delete it.

```
sed '/^showBuilder()$/d'
```

You might find simpler to just:

```
grep -vxF 'showBuilder()'
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern keeps `def` lines, lines that start with whitespace, and empty lines:

```bash
grep -E '^(def|[[:blank:]]|$)' file.py
```

If you want to remove any line that invokes any of the defined functions:

```bash
grep -o -P '^def \K\w+' file.py \
| sed 's/^/^/' \
| grep -v -f - file.py
```